# Multiple application android:name tags in Unity android manifest

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, branch.io, soomla

I want to use Branch.io and Soomla plugin in an Unity project and both plugins need to modify android:name in Unity android manifest:

```xml
... 
<application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" 
     android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" 
     android:name="com.soomla.SoomlaApp" 
     android:name="io.branch.unity.BranchUnityApp">
...
```

I know we can't put multiple android:name in application tag, Is there any way to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Branch plugin with other plugins which also modifies the application class, you can follow the documentation mentioned [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/unity/#support-branch-with-different-plugins).

Comment: Is there anyway to solve this without Android knowledge?